# Cannot find visible element

Tags: java, selenium, automation

[image: here is the element of the text]

I need help in finding unique element to find these text. i don't know why my xpath is not working please check: image attached is the element for the text.

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='"+viz+"']/h2[text()='"+reports+"']")));
```

wherein

```
String reports = Overdue Stock Analysis 
String viz = dashlet-wrapper
```

error message is this :

> Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of all elements located by By.xpath:
>   //div[@class='dashlet-wrapper']/h2[text()='Overdue Stock Analysis']
>   (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Can you post the link to the page?

Comment: Can you tell us what does `System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dashlet-wrapper']/h2[text()='Overdue Stock Analysis']")).size());` prints.

Comment: sorry it is  not possible due to right and access it is not easily navigate by any user

Comment: Have you verified that the element is not in an IFRAME? Also, you are waiting for ALL elements to be visible... have you checked to see if there is a second (or more) element that matches that locator that might never become visible? This happens at times when the mobile/tablet version exists on the page also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the xpath I have mentioned in the expected condition for finding the element and 
if there is only one element which is required to be fetched through the xpath, you should use `visibilityOfElementLocated` instead of the method `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` as `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` is used to check the visibility of a element list and not just a single element.

You can use `visibilityOfElementLocated` like:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions. visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='"+viz+"']//h2[@data-title='"+reports+"']")));
```

Comment: `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy`  will wait for either one element or list of web elements. But the exception he's getting tells something else.

Comment: @cruisepandey i have modified the answer and added the new xpath in my answer